# why 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' happens when XAML is valid

Tags: xaml, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.uwp

An exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in myproj.UWP.McgInterop.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The text associated with this error code could not be found.

Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key category [Line: 0 Position: 0]

Comment: Error looks pretty clear to me, `Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key category ` Show your code that is erroring

Comment: You are setting the resource key either from `Page.Resources`/`App.Resources` or Standard Resources that has a spelling mistake. Check where you are setting the resources and make sure the spelling is correct. Unfortunately XAML Designer does not show swiggly error when the spelling of resource is incorrect.

Comment: @AVK - you are right .. spelling mistake ... you can answer it and I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the resource key either from `Page.Resources`/`App.Resources` or Standard `Resources` that has a spelling mistake. Check where you are setting the resources and make sure the spelling is correct. Unfortunately XAML Designer does not show squiggly error when the spelling of resource is incorrect